# How to comment multiple lines of code in visual studios

Tags: python, visual-studio, comments

I'm very new to coding so I decided to try Python and downloaded Visual Studio, but I am not sure how you can comment out multiple lines of code.

Comment: Normal Python commenting across multiple lines is `"""` triple quotes at the start of the comment and `"""` another set of triple quotes at the end. Doesn't matter if they are double or single quotes they just have to match. It may or may not apply in VS but probably worth a check :)

Answer (score 4):

Normally in Visual Studio Community 2019, multi line comments are done by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to remove comments. But this is unavailable when using python for some reason.

Personally, for learning to write Python I would recommend using Visual Studio Code, instead of Visual Studio. VS Code is a much more light weight package (install size approx 300MB compared to several GB) This means that it opens in a fraction of the time.
In VS Code the Python extension will provide all of your python needs and allow you to toggle block comments by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can use triple quotes to comment multiple lines of code. Example:

```
"""
comment
still comment
"""
print('Hello world!')
```

The text in the quotes is commented, but the print statement below it is not and will work.

Answer (score 0):

there is a short cut for most of the languages in VS code :
Ctrl+/
edit: you need to select the lines that you intend to comment out

Answer (score 0):

to comment out multiple lines in python you can use triple quotes like this:

```
"""
this is line 1 of my comment
and this is line 2 of my comment
this is link 3
"""
```

you get the point as long as there are triple quotes at the beginning of the first line and at the end of the last line

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl + Shift + A` did the job for me. It will put you """ at the beginning and at the end of your selected text.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use the shortcut key `ctrl + k` and `ctrl + c` to comment. To uncomment just hit the `ctrl + k` and `ctrl + u`

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the edit button in Visual Studio at the bottom is how you can comment lines out.

"toggle line comment" for me done with ctrl + ',
but could be something else for you

"toggle block comment" for me is done with shift + alt + A,
but could be something else for you

In both cases does the first click comment and clicking again uncomments